# In JSX why is this invalid: {...{ type: 'button', ...props }}

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to use the attribute `type` if it is provided in the props, if not I want to provide `button` to the attribute `type`.

```
    <button
      {...{ type: 'button', ...props }}
    />
```

This does not work and provides `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

If I do this it works fine:

```
const newProps = {type: 'button', ...props}

  //...
  <button
    {...newProps}
```

I am now doing this instead, just curious why the first example doesn't work, but the second example does:

```
  <button
    {...props}
    type="button"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just write:

```
<button
   { type: 'button', ...props }
/>
```

However, I would go with your last approach (my best practice):

```
  <button
    {...props}
    type="button"
  />
```

My best because firstly defined attribute is always takes first place in html.